# SSH failed to create session no buffer space available

Tags: linux, ssh

When I try to connect to my machine trough SSH, after I enter my username and password, the screen then "hangs" and nothing happends

[image]

Luckily, I still have shell a open from yesterday on a different PC in the office which I connact to with Anydesk where I can see the logs, it reads:

```
Nov 09 10:45:55 localhost.localdomain sshd[2472713]: Accepted password for root from 192.168.1.10 port 53997 ssh2
Nov 09 10:46:46 localhost.localdomain sshd[2472713]: pam_systemd(sshd:session): Failed to create session: No buffer space available
Nov 09 10:47:16 localhost.localdomain sshd[2472713]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 09 10:47:46 localhost.localdomain sshd[2472713]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user root
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Im wondering how I can resolve this issue and how I can  prevent this from happening in the future? It would be ideal to always have access to this machine, is there any way to "force space" if there is none, as the logs state?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://serverfault.com/questions/131935/network-error-no-buffer-space-available